# Error al implementar Dagger hilt con gradle version catalog

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

Estoy tratando de implementar dagger hilt en gradle version catalog, hago todas las importaciones y las hace bien, pero al momento de compilar, obtengo un error que no se por que esta pasando y no encuentro una solucion clara a esto, alguien podria ayudarmae con este problema que tengo???

1. Error
2. libs.version.toml
3. gradle proyecto
4. gradle app

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]